# Xamarin.Forms - ListView entirely in XAML

Tags: c#, xamarin.ios, xamarin, xamarin.android, xamarin.forms

We have a few screens that should effectively be `UITableViews` on iOS that have a static number of rows and different types of cells.

Is there a way to define this in XAML with Xamarin.Forms, and not have to setup a binding to `ItemsSource`? Like if I just want to define two `EntryCells` and then a `TextCell`?

My first attempt is this example, but I just see the equivalent of `Cell.ToString()` in each row:

```
  <ListView>
    <ListView.ItemsSource>
        <x:Array Type="{x:Type Cell}">
            <EntryCell Text="{Binding Phone}" />
            <EntryCell Text="{Binding Code}" />
            <TextCell Text="LOGIN" Command="{Binding Login}"/>
        </x:Array>
    </ListView.ItemsSource>
  </ListView>
```

Answer (score 1):

Considering you want static cells with different templates / layout for each cell, have you tried **Xamarin.Forms TableView**? http://iosapi.xamarin.com/?link=T%3aXamarin.Forms.TableView

```
<TableView>
    <TableView.Root>
        <TableSection Title="Login">        
            <EntryCell Text="{Binding Phone}" />
            <EntryCell Text="{Binding Code}" />
            <TextCell Text="LOGIN" Command="{Binding Login}"/>
        </TableSection>
    </TableView.Root>
</TableView>
```

Admittedly this seems to give you a non customisable section header at the time of writing (but this will probably improve).

Comment: We tried this, but do not want any headers in our UI for the `TableSection` at all. But if you set `Title` to blank, there is still a blank clickable row as a header on Android. `ListView` didn't have this issue.

Comment: fwiw, this empty header is still present in Xamarin.Forms v2.5.0.91635, so still not an ideal substitute.